# C# WPF Border Backgrould color changed from code hides its content

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, border

I have this issue which i cannot overcome.

WPF code:

```
<Border x:Name="Border1" Margin="5" Padding="3" BorderThickness="2" BorderBrush="Black">
   <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center">
       <TextBlock x:Name="TB_Sample" Text="Sample Text"/>
   </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

When I modify Background property of border in WPF the *"Sample Text"* is visible on top of the background color.

When I modify background color in C# code:

```
Border1.Backgroud = Brushes.Red;
```

The background color covers the *"Sample Text"* so it is no longer visible.

Is there a way to change the background in code without covering the content?

Comment: With only the code you gave above, it should work as you have described (i.e. text is visible on background). Does your code do anything else that could be relevant? Can you give a _complete_ example (see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)).

Comment: @FrankM whole wpf code here https://pastebin.com/fvV1yGyX Borers which I am having problem with are in lines 48-71.
C# code has just the line which i posted in original question (in few different places with different colors)

Comment: I have tried it, and it works for me (I see black text on red background). Again, try creating a [mcve].